# Udp address for iOS Device for TouchOSC

Tags: networking, udp, osc

I am attempting to address an iPad not by ip address but by hostname for TouchOSC.  I am using Max/MSP and the udpsend object to transmit label information to TouchOSC on an ipad.  Via the touchosc website it says to use `<device name> [<device model>] (TouchOSC)` to address the tablet.  But these messages seem to disappear into the ether.  Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue.  Simple use iOS_device_name.local (like any mac computer network hostname address) and your TouchOSC messages should land squarely in the right place.  Hope this helps someone!